# jquery 1.4.4 send accept header exactly as 'application/json'

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

The third party service I'm using is very particular. I'm trying to set the accepts header to

```
Accept: application/json
```

But jquery 1.4.4 won't send just that. It keeps sending a variation, i.e.:

```
Accept: */*, application/json
```

I've tried a few variations, i.e. the one below. How can I get it to send just 'Accept: application/json' in the accepts header?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/rest/cms.country",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'get',
    success: function () {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried seting `dataType` parameter? `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @Zefiryn setting the datatype parameter didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the W3C spec, setting the request header is supposed to append to any existing value, so it's already '*/*' and you setting it before the request appends 'application/json'.

Also, according to [this](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/470) the spec now requires '*/*' as an accept value, so your server is violating the spec (I know not your issue here).

What you want is the browser to clear out the existing value of '*/*' before setting yours, so maybe call:

```
setRequestHeader('Accept', '')
```

before your AJAX request? This is going to be browser-dependent so you're probably in for some IE fun.

Comment: By referencing the spec, I then found out that that this was not the root cause of my problem. Thanks!!!